# In a song, if somebody wanted to say to their deceased mom, "We loved you so much." what form of love would you use?

Tags: usage, kanji

Would I use "Aishita" or something else? The child is a 16 year old.

Comment: Presumably you mean "deceased" and not "diseased"?

Comment: Yeah, whoops, corrected it.

Comment: Why でした? An ordinary 16-year-old boy would not usually use that to his mom unless he's being formal. Without knowing the overall atmosphere of the remaining part of the song, this question is very hard to answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Japanese, and I assumed でした referred to past tense? 

The overall atmosphere is very dark. And it's about the loneliness the boy and his brother faced following her death.

Comment: でした is a past tense form, but it's the past tense of です, which is used to express politeness to the listener, and wouldn't typically be used between family members. The past tense that would be in the appropriate register would be だった.

Comment: @AlexCunningham I mean, "daisuki" is not wrong at all, but "deshita" is a (past) *polite* copula. A son might use "deshita" when writing a letter to his mother in a formal and 
solemn tone, and that's what I meant by "atmosphere". So is the tone of this song like "Hey mom thanks so much" or "Dear our mother, we appreciate your kindness"? This affects how much 愛 would be acceptable.

Comment: It's, "Precious mother, sweet mother, we loved you so much."

Answer (score 4):

Unlike 恋 (*koi*) which refers to romantic love, technically speaking, you can use 愛 (*ai*) to refer to familial love. But it's basically a fairly big word, and I believe most 16-year-old boys would feel embarrassed to use it. 大好き (*daisuki*) should be much safer most of the time. 愛 might be safely used if the writer is mature and the song contains stiff words or words related Christianity/philosophy, but your song does not seem to be like this.